# Unable to install the package devtools onto Jupiter Lab workspace

Tags: r, jupyter, devtools

[image]I am new to Jupyter Labs, but have recently started using it with R kernel.

I am working on a workspace hosted by the CGIAR's Collaborative GARDIAN Labs (CG Labs) that facilitate the collaboratively writing of scripts and running of analyses via Jupyter, which has been extended to support smooth data exchange via the CG Labs Globus Servers. (https://labs.scio.systems/html/about.html)

Normally I simply use `install.packages("devtools")` to install devtools into my RStudio. This approach has worked for other packages in Jupiter Lab but not for "devtools". When I try I get errors related to the dependencies:

```
Warning message in install.packages("devtools"):
“installation of package ‘xxxx’ had non-zero exit status
....
“installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status, 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'”
```

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on here? I have my library set as `"/opt/conda/lib/R/library"`..

I suspect the issue to be related to my library specifications, however, I have no idea how to investigate this nor change the library specifications.

Comment: Do you have rtools installed to compile the imported packages?

Comment: Hi @SmokeyShakers,
No. But I have tried installing all the devtools dependencies separately prior to installing devtools but that did not work. Is rtools the only package that might interfer? One issue I hear from people is that I dont have the R-essentials installed in my .libPath() – however im not sure how to do that.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers,

I am running on a macOS, so it should not be necessary, but also how would you install Rtools into the Jupyter Lab?

Comment: Ah,  didn’t realize that.  It was just a guess. The zip package looks like it fails first. It is the first devtools import that requires compilation. Can you install zip alone?